# Placement of "tant"?

Tags: ordre-des-mots

All these examples seem to be...different. I cannot make sense of it.

> Il a déjà tant fait.
>
> Il travaille tant !
>
> J'ai dû partir, tant j'étais fatigué.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the placement of *tant* is weird. A [good dictionary](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tant) will explain the rules. Mostly. The adverb *tant* has a slightly dated feel, which may be a cause or a consequence of its placement partly obeying rules of old French.

Normally *tant* comes after the verb, which is the default place for an adverb.

> Il travaille tant !
>   Il travaille tellement !
>   Il travaille beaucoup.

With a compound tense, *tant* usually goes between the auxiliary and the verb.

> Il a déjà tant fait.
>   Il en a déjà fait tellement.

*Tant* can also act as a subordinating conjunction. In that case, it is naturally placed at the beginning of the clause.

> J'ai dû partir, tant j'étais fatigué.
>   J'étais si fatigué que j'ai dû partir.
>   J'étais tellement fatigué que j'ai dû partir.